# WFC/IIS Request Not response - Timeout 5 minutes?

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, request, timeout

I am working with WCF on .Net 4.0 over IIS 7.5, I have a service that according to the parameters I receive can take a few seconds or 5 minutes in the most extreme case. I return a ServiceResult `<List <MyDTO>>`

In the case that it takes a short time, everything goes well, but the problem arises when you need more than 5 minutes to respond.

The strange thing is that it seems that the server never responds, that is, it does not give the expected result, nor an error, only the timeout I have set in 30 minutes after that time elapses.

I turn down the timeout to 6 minutes and the same ... at 5 minutes the service should issue the response but it never arrives, so when the time reaches 6 minutes I receive a timeout error.

I have a log file that saves step by step and everything seems perfect but for some reason, that answer does not leave the server

I imagine that there is some timeout configured somewhere that I am not considering, but it catches my attention that it does not explode anywhere

Notes:

- The server is in an Amazon virtual machine
- In my web.config I have set all timeouts to 30 minutes
- In development (IIS Express) it works well obviously hahaha
- The problem appears both in the app that consumes it and in the WCF Test Client

Comment: frankly, I think you're trying to solve this the wrong way; if something takes 5 minutes, synchronous is jut not a good API - this feels more like a "call me back when you're done", or "issue a token, then keep polling with that token to see if it has finished" scenario

Comment: Yes, what happens is that in most cases it takes less than 10 seconds, I am considering to turn to that model, but I would also like to know what is happening in this scenario. Thank you!

Comment: To expand on Marc's comment, frameworks like SignalR might be a better option, as the two sides can exchange messages bidirectionally, and long connections are accepted (not like WCF).